# Is there a theoretical limit to the thrust produced by a propeller in amosphere?

Tags: aerodynamics

Assumptions:

- Indestructible variable-pitch aircraft propeller
- Arbitrary motor torque and velocity
- Standard pressure and atmospheric conditions at sea level
- Low, near-zero relative airspeed

This may be a question better suited for XKCD's "what if" but I'm wondering if there is a theoretical limit to the thrust that a propeller can provide in an atmosphere provided with an arbitrarily powerful and fast motor.

My thoughts on this question so far:

- When the propeller goes fast enough that the tips start generating supersonic shock-waves, drag is greatly increased but functional aircraft with supersonic propellers have been built before [(see Thunderscreech)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_XF-84H_Thunderscreech)
- I think that at high enough speeds there might be "atmospheric cavitation" where the propeller blade's wake is essentially a vacuum. Go fast enough, and the spinning propeller becomes essentially a very loud disk-shaped vacuum with no thrust

Because of this, my hypothesis is that while in the beginning thrust of the system increases with speed (especially if the pitch of the propellers is continuously adjusted), eventually a propeller speed will be reached where it is moving so fast that it creates a situation where no air can actually flow "through" the propeller anymore, causing net thrust to approach zero.
Any ideas?

Comment: I imagine at some point the air gets so hot it turns into plasma...assuming the propeller is made of an indestructible material (one criteria you failed to specify).

Comment: @DKNguyen Indestructible propeller is the first point

Comment: Must have missed it.

Answer (score 0):

propeller tips can be forced above mach 1, but their effectiveness falls off so strongly in that regime that it makes no sense to operate them there. Consider the following:

Propeller-driven racing planes operate over a range of ambient pressures and temperatures i.e., air densities. The speed of sound varies enough through those ranges that a pilot must control their propeller speed from one day of racing to the next so as to always stay below mach 1 at the prop tips, else they waste horsepower on dragging shock waves around (making noise without winning races) instead of generating thrust (which makes speed and wins races).

This means that the *practical limit* to propeller propulsion is the speed of sound at the prop tips.

Comment: Supersonic propellers are possible, but they have serious drawbacks. [The Insane Engineering of the Thunderscreech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIGlQBx4tys)